# Closing output stream 'misbehaving'?

Tags: java

In the following code:

```
    for(int i = 5; i  <= 100; i+=5)
    {
        linearSurprise(i); // Function calling 'System.out.print()'

        System.setOut(outStream); // Reassigns the "standard" output stream.

        System.out.println("Value of i: " + i); // Outputting the value to the .txt file.

        outStream.close(); // 'outStrem' is closed so that when I recall my function, output will 
                           // will be sent to the console and not file.

      // After debugging, I notice that nothing is being displayed to either the console or file, 
      // but everything else is still working fine. 
    }
```

I am calling a function 'linearSurprise' and in that function I output some information to the console. Once the function call is over, I redirect the value of 'i' to a text file. This works for the first iteration of the loop, but as soon as I call 'outStream.close()' no output whatsoever is displayed in the next iteration(console or file). Does anyone know why this is happening? Also what would be a workaround to this problem?

Comment: why are you writing to System.out? Why don't you just write to the file directly?

Comment: Include more code so we can see the big picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *closing* the `OutputStream` *inside* your loop, and `System.out` is now closed; you have to reassign an open `OutputStream` to it to be able to write any more output.

For this purpose, you really ought to be writing directly to the `FileOutputStream` instead; there's no value in redirecting `System.out` to it, and it leads to problems like this one.

```
PrintStream outStream = new PrintStream(File outputFile);
for(int i = 5; i <= 100; i += 5)
{
    linearSurprise(i);
    outStream.println("Value of i: " + i);
}
outStream.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

This assumption is invalid:

> 'outStrem' is closed so that when I recall my function, output will be sent 
>   to the console and not file.

Why would it magically go back to the console? It will just be written to a closed stream instead, which will cause an exception which is swallowed by `PrintStream`.

If you want to set it back to the original console stream, you need to do that explicitly:

```
PrintStream originalOutput = System.out;

// Do stuff...

System.setOut(originalOutput); // Now we can write back to the console again
```

Answer (score 1):

Close your file after the loop

```
outStream.close();
```

Comment: I'm trying to alternate between outputting to the txt file and console, that's why it is in the loop....

Answer (score 1):

```
System.setOut(outStream); // Reassigns the "standard" output stream.
for(int i = 5; i  <= 100; i+=5)
    {
        linearSurprise(i); // Function call


        System.out.println("Value of i: " + i); // Outputting the value to the .txt file.

will 
                           // will be sent to the console and not file.

      // After debugging, I notice that nothing is being displayed to either the console or file, 
      // but everything else is still working fine. 
    }
    outStream.close(); // 'outStrem' is closed so that when I recall my function, output
```

If you close the outStream after you are finished writing to it instead of after one iteration it should work.

Comment: I'm trying to alternate between outputting to the txt file and console, that's why it is in the loop....

Comment: Once you close the stream you need to create a new to be able to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `outStream.flush()` instead of  `outStream.close()` inside loop. It may work. As `outStream.close();`  will close your file. it is better to close after loop completion.

Answer (score 0):

Since you call CLose() the stream is disposed thus no longer existing anymore

Answer (score 0):

Print to File as follow:

```
outStream.println("What ever you want");
```

And close the stream after the loop.

Dont't setOut(outStream);